# Date Range is starting with Plus

Tags: javascript, date

I have created a small function which give all dates between two dates.

but this is starting from Plus 1 date.

Here's my code (also on Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9jb0483/)):

```js
function DateRangeArr(to, from) {
    console.log(to);
    console.log(from);
    var Dateresult = [];

    var end = new Date(from);
    var loop = new Date(to);

    while (loop <= end) {
        Dateresult.push({ 'total': 0, 'log_date': loop });
        var newDate = loop.setDate(loop.getUTCDate() + 1);
        loop = new Date(newDate);
    }
    return Dateresult;
}

console.log(DateRangeArr('2020-12-05','2020-12-12'));
```

It's giving me results starting from 2020-12-06 to 2020-12-13. Also will it gives result depending upon user time zone ?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) rather than off-site. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. [Here's how to do an on-site Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). **Edit:** Actually, your code was complete, so I copied it into a snippet for you.

Comment: Note that passing a `Date` object into `new Date` to clone it is **not** reliable cross-browser. Instead, pass the underlying time value. For example, change `loop = new Date(newDate);` to `loop = new Date(+newDate);` (note the unary `+`). I don't think that's the problem you're having, but it's something to change regardless for reliability.

Comment: You're using dates with no times. Do you want those to be at midnight *local* time, or midnight *UTC*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on that could account for the problem.

- (This is probably the thing you're seeing) You're changing the state of the `Date` instance that you added to the array after adding it. That changes the instance that's in the array.
- Since `"2020-12-05"` is a date-only string, it's parsed as UTC in specification-compliant browsers (see the rules at [`Date.parse`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse)), so the `Date` objects will represent midnight on that date UTC rather than midnight on that date in your local timezone. If you want them to reliably be midnight local time, add `T00:00` to the string. If you want them to be parsed reliably as UTC, you should be able to use them as-is, but the spec moved around on this (ES2015 said they should be parsed as local time, not UTC, before being updated by ES2016) so to get UTC reliably, add `T00:00Z` to it. (My understanding is that the spec allows just adding a `Z`, **but** others read the spec differently, and both Safari's JavaScriptCore and Firefox's SpiderMonkey reject `new Date("2020-12-05Z")`, so add `T00:00Z`.) Or use `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day))` instead.
- You're mixing up accessors here: `loop.setDate(loop.getUTCDate() + 1)`. That's using the UTC accessor to *get* the date, but then the local time accessor to *set* it. You need to be consistent in order to add a day to the date.
- You haven't said how you're using the resulting array of `Date` objects, but just note that the date they show may *seem* off if (for instance) you parse them as UTC but then display the result in local time or vice-versa, because of the time zone offset.
- You have `to` and `from` reversed in your code. You're using them consistently, but it's quite hard to read. :-) When building an array in date order, it goes *from* the earlier date *to* the later date.

Here's a version updated to work entirely in UTC; the resulting `Date` objects represent midnight UTC on each of the dates:

```js
function dateRangeArr(from, to) {
    console.log(from);
    console.log(to);
    var dates = [];

    var end = new Date(to + "T00:00Z");
    var loop = new Date(from + "T00:00Z");

    while (loop <= end) {
        dates.push({ "total": 0, "log_date": new Date(+loop) });
        loop.setUTCDate(loop.getUTCDate() + 1);
    }
    return dates;
}

console.log(dateRangeArr("2020-12-05","2020-12-12"));
```

*(I've also updated the function and variable names to be more consistent with standard practice in JavaScript, since the function isn't a constructor function.)*

Here's a version that works in local time instead:

```js
function dateRangeArr(from, to) {
    console.log(from);
    console.log(to);
    var dates = [];

    var end = new Date(to + "T00:00");
    var loop = new Date(from + "T00:00");

    while (loop <= end) {
        dates.push({ "total": 0, "log_date": new Date(+loop) });
        loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return dates;
}

console.log(dateRangeArr("2020-12-05","2020-12-12"));
```

Which you use depends on whether you want the `Date` instances to represent midnight UTC (use the UTC version) or midnight local time (use the local time version).

Comment: Re "*If you want them to reliably be UTC, add a Z to the string*". `new Date('2020-12-12Z')` produces an invalid Date in Safari because it's not a supported date string in either ECMA-262 or ISO 8601. Date–only forms don't have timezones and only ECMAScript treats them as UTC (a silly move by TC39). :-)

Comment: @RobG - ***God*** the spec is such a mess around this stuff, even now. Thanks for pointing out Safari doesn't handle it. There are things in the spec that suggest date-only strings can't have timezone information, and there are things in the spec that suggest they can. To me, there's more supporting the latter than the former, but both JavaScriptCore (Safari) and SpiderMonkey (Firefox) reject `new Date("2020-12-05Z")` so whatever the spec says, the pragmatic thing to do is not to rely on it and use `new Date("2020-12-05T00:00Z")` instead (or use `new Date(Date.UTC(...))`). :-|

Comment: Just FWIW: Supporting the case that date-only strings can't have timezone indicators: It's true that the [date time string format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) section only refers to timezone information in relation to date-time strings. And the [`parse`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse) section prefaces everything by saying *"If the String conforms to the Date Time String Format..."*. But supporting the case they can: `parse` says missing elements have defaults, so in theory `2020-12-05Z` should be treated just like `2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z`. *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* When defining that, the `parse` section expressly says *"When the **HH**, mm, or ss elements are absent, "00" is used"* *(my emphasis)* clearly allowing for the idea that all three would be missing. (Safari and Firefox don't allow `"2020-12-05TZ"`, either.) Also, it says *"When the UTC offset representation is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time"* which again suggests it's valid to have a timezone indicator on a date-only string. (That part used to be in the format section, but it got moved.) *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* **But** as you say, Safari doesn't allow it, and Firefox doesn't either, so there we are. :-)